# How to render an object without its shadow?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, camera, light, shadows

I am trying to delete the shadow from the heart but I can't:

[image]

Comment: Tangentially related, Rendering object without reflection: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/142924/make-an-object-not-reflected-by-a-surface/142925#142925

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One option is *turning off* the *Shadow property per object* (*Properties > Object > Cycles Settings*):

[image]

As of Blender 2.8x the *Cycles Settings* panel has been renamed to *Visibility* and the *Shadow* property is now part of the new *Ray Visibility* subpanel. For Eevee you can only turn off the *Shadow property per light* for the time being (*Properties > Object Data > Light*):

[image]

---

Another option for *Cycles* is using the *Light Path* node. Plug *Is Shadow Ray* into the *Factor* socket of a *Mix Shader* and use a *Transparent BSDF* for the second *Shader* input:

[image]

**Result**

[image]