# How do I remove the shadow of an emitting geometry?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, light, geometry

How do I remove the shadow cast by the rectangle using the cycles renderer?

[image]

Comment: Try using a cylinder instead of a plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think it's a shadow, but more of a spot the emission of the plane cannot reach because it's not pointed to that direction. Would giving the plane a bit of depth solve your issue?

Edit: Another solution i could think of is replacing the plane with a thin cylinder.

Comment: Worked with the cylinder.
thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

Extrude the plane slightly or use a cylinder. What you see is not the shadow, rather the geometry emits no light to the ground in this spot.

[image]

In case there are multiple light sources in the scene, disable the *Shadow* property for each emitter *(Object Properties > Cycles Settings)*, see [How to render an object without its shadow?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/48834/31447)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this node set up [image: nodes]
The lightpath acts a fac into the mix so the shadow rays are transparent.